# Get the page URL (no Action Url) of the page I am visiting in MVC

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, url, routes

I am using MVC. 
I have a layout page that has some components that call the controllers. One of this component is the menù that call the action `GetMenu(...)`.
And then I have the page that use that layout page. I reach this page calling an action (`Index`) of another controller.
So.. Everytime I call at least two actions:

1. /HomeController/GetMenu
2. /ServiceXXXController/Index

Now, from the action `GetMenu`, I need to take the url of the page I am visiting. In MVC, it means that I need to take the url of the other action (`/ServiceXXXController/Index`) but when I do `Request.Url.*` I obtain the url of the menu (`/HomeController/GetMenu`)

There is a way to obtain the url of that page I am visiting?

Thank you.

Comment: How exactly is the layout "calls" the `GetMenu` action? If it's invoked as a child-action, your `Request.Url` should definitely remain the "parent" Url. If you call `GetMenu` from the client (using Ajax), then you'll have to rely on `Request.UrlReferrer`

Comment: yes.. I am using Angularjs... thank you!

Comment: If you're already using Angular, some would argue that it's much more sensible to let Angular inject the current Url into the template instead of rendering it on the server and relying on the Referrer header.

Comment: that was the other doubt I had, honestly

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the URL to get menu while rendering it.